# How to prevent stored proc from returning intermediate recordsets?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, executescalar

Problem context : I use VisualStudio 2008 and typed datasets, which offer an "easy" access to `executescalar()`
Execute scalar returns the value of the first field of the first row of the **first recorset** (*this last part being often omitted*)

The problem with this behaviour is that most often you want to make some other requests *before* you compute the value to be returned with a final `select @returnValue` statement.

So my question is, in general, **How do you prevent a SP to return intermediate recordsets?** 
(I tried SET FMTONLY ON/OFF but is has unwanted side behaviour)

Another related question is : how do you prevent a T-SQL **UPDATE statement** from returning the updated rows ? Sometimes you use UPDATE to simply UPDATE ...

thanks!

sample:

BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @c int
select  @c=(select count(*) from work where ...)
select @c   -- so ExecuteScalar() works 
update sousblocs set myfield = @c
       where ...

select @c --after the update, won't be seen by ExecuteScalar()
return @c --useless for ExecuteScalar
```

END

*this was my problem, and it can be solved with the first "select @c"; but I nevertheless wonder if you can disable recorset output....*

Comment: "you want to make some other requests" - please show us some example code from one of your sprocs to illustrate what you mean here

Comment: I mean, for instance, you compute a value  to be stored with an update, and you want to return that value. In this case, the update will be the first recordset to be returned

Answer (score 1):

1 - Don't have multiple select statements in your stored proc without a target.  I.e. if you run `SELECT 1,2,3` and then `SELECT 4,5,6` it will return 2 recordsets.

2 - I'm not sure why you are getting records back when you run an update.  Try setting `SET NOCOUNT ON` to turn off the "xx rows affected" messages.

Comment: "SET NOCOUNT ON" already set. returned messages are not the problem. statements like "select @var= somefunc(..." do not return recordsets, and there is not point in SELECTING if you don't want a recordset. That is right. But the update statement is an issue ... unless you consider that you update with a known value, that you can select beforehand ...

Comment: @oldbrazil - What are you getting back exactly?